# Is there a way to get line numbers or stack traces from an Error object in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, exception

In order to [ease debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183159/how-do-i-debug-my-asynchronous-promise-based-code-if-the-library-is-swallowing) some tricky async Javascript code that is misbehaving in Internet Explorer, I want to know if it is possible to, given an Error object, get useful information about its original location.

Firefox, Chrome, Opera and I guess all the other nice browsers all let me do it:

```
try{
    throw Error('My custom error message');
}catch(e){
    console.log(e.stack)
}
```

but none of the properties I tried (`error.stack` and `error.lineNumber`) work on Internet Explorer. **Is there a way to get at this information on Internet Explorer, using Javascript only?** Since the IE REPL will show the original line number for unhandled exceptions even if they were caught and rethrown in a different line, I assume the information I want is being stored *somewhere*, but I could not find out if there is a public way to get at it.

Answer (score 2):

These properties aren't available in IE.  You can get some of the way by using the `arguments.callee` graph.  However, this method doesn't work too well if you have a lot of anonymous functions or use `bind()` frequently.

See `goog.debug.getStacktrace()` in the [Closure Library's debug package](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/4/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_debug_debug.js.source.html) for a sample implementation.  `goog.debug.normalizeErrorObject()` may also be useful to you.

Comment: I have tons of anonymous functions and things that use `bind`. Am I screwed? :(

Comment: Try it out :)  It may still be better than nothing.